# How to insert same data record to multiple table on Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using `yii2-advanced`. I've several table :

1. `tb_user`:(`iduser(PK)`,`username`),
2. `tb_profile`:(`id`,`iduser(FK)`),
3. `tb_status`:(`id`,`iduser(FK)`)

My question is how can i insert `iduser(PK)` from `tb_user` to `iduser(FK)` on `tb_profile` and `tb_status` after i push the signup button. 
For a while i think i must to do some modification of `bevahiours()` function on `User` model and i found some error, or adding `trigger` syntax on the table ? (i think this is not a good ways). 

Is there anyone who can help me, how to solve my problem ?
this is the `User` model before the modification :

```
<?php
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;


class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'created_at',
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated_at',
                ],
                'value' => function () {return date('Y-m-d h:m:s');},
            ],

        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

}
?>
```

The `Controller` :

```
public function actionSignup()
{
    $model = new SignupForm();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($user = $model->signup()) {
            if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                return $this->goHome();
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of record that you need to insert?

Comment: @arogachev on `tb_user` i've data record (`id`,`username`). Now, i want the record of `tb_user` will be added in `tb_profile` and `tb_status`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar situation in one of my project where i had 2 tables like `user`,`user_image` where `user_id` was foreign key to add the path.

For those kind of situation you can use either of following approach

1.Insert record in both table on click of `signup` button. You will have to write update action accordingly.

```
 $user = new User();
 $user->name = "John"
 $user->email = "John@gmail.com"
 //Add if any other fields in table
 $user->save(); //save the record

 $user_image = new UserImage();
 $user_image->user_id = $user->id;
 $user_image->image = "image path"
 //Add any other images here
 $user_image->save();//save the record
```

2.You can also call `create` action of `UserImage` and do the same. If you use this approach than you might also need to use any other unique column to find the `id` of that user and use it to insert new record,for example in my table `email` is unique column so i can write following code in `UserImage` and get the `id`

```
$user = User::findOne(['email' => 'john@gmail.com']);//this will return whole row 
$user_image->user_id = $user->id;
 $user_image->image = "image path"
 //Add any other images here
 $user_image->save();//save the record
```

And that way you can use the code as per it suits your need

Thank you

Comment: how if i want to insert `id` as foreign key in related table ? what should i do ?

Comment: @Adi updated the answer. i hope thats what you want to do because i am still not clear what you wants to do

Comment: @Adi i got your point now but still i suggested all approaches to you now you can use any of those which fits your situation.

Comment: with this signup case of `yii2-advanced` I still do not understand, in which part of my file should I change ? `SiteController file` with signup function ? or `User` model file ?

Comment: @Adi i have updated the answer and yeah you need to change in `SiteController` action for signup. I dont know much about the structure of your project but if the url is `web/site/signup` than you need to change code in `SiteController`

Comment: sorry my bad, i forgot about adding my `SiteController` on my question, i will update it now @Mike Ross

Comment: @Adi yes you need to change in `signup` action. I would suggest using 1st approach of my answer.

Comment: this is more suitable way to this kind of situation